# Memory management allocating

Tags: memory-management, ram

I can't understand how memory management works. Can somebody explain/draw me how it will be correctly? Thank You for any advice.

1. Allocating a contiguous area of ​​memory

   - We have tasks P1 and P2 come in time in a row.
   - P1 requires 123kB of memory and P2 requires 240kB of memory.

   b) Draw to status 2 position memory with the advent of P1

   c) Draw to status 3 position memory with the advent of P2!

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s9iN.png

Comment: That depends *heavily* on the individual allocator, doesn't it?

Comment: well I don't think it depends on allocator, I guess I figured out. If I'm not wrong it's easy because you can have always only one task because it's doesn't support multiprogramming. But I've next problem I need find value of relocation register. Anyone know how I can find them? "Write down the value of relocation registers for each state and role in them, if there were to compress". I've no idea how I can find it.

Comment: I know at least two allocation schemes which result in rather different use of memory. A [buddy allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) would round the sizes for both the OS and the processes up (to powers of two). A first-fit allocator with sufficiently small granularity, on the other hand, would put the blocks right next to each other with no fragmentation. Now, your class may only be concerned with a specific (class of) memory allocation scheme(s) but for all *I* know there are many ways this could go down.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when memory allocations are done by any OS,it usually finishes the task of allocating for smaller values first because such locations can easily be found.

Whereas incase of a request of a large space,the OS will first try to find such a space on the physical RAM.If that fails,then the OS resorts to paging or other virtual memory methods.This usually takes more time,hence allocation of smaller spaces is done first.

Hence in your case,task P1 will be give higher priority and 123kB will be allocated for it first,then followed by task P2.

But the process priority of the programs can make a difference i.e. if task P2 has a higher priority of being executed than task P1,then task P2 will be give higher priority and 240kB will be allocated for it first,then followed by task P1.